# Disconnect and reconnect ttyUSB0 programmatically in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, serial-port, tty

Trying to solve [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21525654/linux-termios-how-to-handle-negative-result-of-select) (ttyUSB0 that works properly than stop working after about 1hr)I'm thinking on if disconnecting and reconnecting the usb device could be a good fix.

So, it is possibile to cut down power to the USB device and repower it programmatically (bash)?

```
# lsusb -t                                        
1-1:1.0: No such file or directory                                              
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=musb-hdrc/1p, 480M             
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=vend., Driver=, 12M                          
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 1, Class=vend., Driver=cp210x, 12M
```

On am335x, kernel 3.2.0, ubuntu core armhf.

```
[    1.784332] usb 1-1: cp210x converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

At the moment I need a complete power cycle to have `ttyUSB0` back.

Comment: If you find the solution to your own question, you should post an answer. You can even accept your own answer if noone offers a better one.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is the solution:

- Find the identity of your usb device.

  ```
  # tree /sys/bus/usb/drivers/cp210x/
  /sys/bus/usb/drivers/cp210x/
  |-- 1-1:1.1 -> ../../../../devices/platform/omap/musb-ti81xx/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.1
  |-- bind
  |-- module -> ../../../../module/cp210x
  |-- remove_id
  |-- uevent
   -- unbind
  ```

So `1-1:1.1` is the identifier of my `ttyUSB0`(it can be discovered also via `dmesg`).

- Then, disconnect the device (as root):

  ```
  # echo -n "1-1:1.1" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/cp210x/unbind
  ```
- reconnect it

  ```
  # echo -n "1-1:1.1" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/cp210x/bind
  ```

At this point I had the same device but with a different name, it was now ttyUSB1 instead of ttyUSB0. 
- To avoid this I added a new rule in `/etc/udev/rules.d/` by creating a new file named `99-usb-serial.rules` with this line:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="10c4", ATTRS{idProduct}=="ea70", ATTRS{serial}=="002DCFAF", SYMLINK+="sameName", MODE:="0666"
```

where `idVendor`, `idProduct` and serial must be the values of your device. This rule will create a new device called `sameName` linked to the `ttyUSB*` device normally generated from the OS.

Comment: to get identifier of my device from dmesg i use this: `dmesg | grep ': pl2303 converter detected' |sed -e '$!d'| awk '{ print $2}'|sed 's/.$//'`

Comment: but this doesn't, power off the usb serial device? how to power off the usb serial

Answer (score 2):

As @Robert Harvey Said,

You first need to find our driver that will help you 'unplug and plug' the usb. Type: `ls /sys/bus/usb/drivers` which should print something like this: `btusb  ftdi_sio  hub  usb  usbfs  usbhid  usbserial_generic  uvcvideo`. These, are all the drivers for each usb device. Now, lets say mine is `ftdi_sio`, which is a device i use to program my arduino (atmega328p chip). I am not sure how Your/other usb devices name themselves there. Like, i dont know which of these is my mouse.
Now, you can see the driver's commands using:
`ls /sys/bus/usb/drivers/ftdi_sio/`, which will print something like: `1-4:1.0  bind  module  uevent  unbind`, Where `1-4:1.0` is the device's characteristic code, and the `bind` and `unbind` command, which are the 'plug' and 'unplug' command respectively.

Now, if i want to unplug programatically the ftdi usb port, i will type:
`echo -n "1-4:1.0" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/ftdi_sio/unbind`
and, to plug it again:
`echo -n "1-4:1.0" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/ftdi_sio/bind`

Now, we can combine all the commands together, with a ';':

`echo -n "1-4:1.0" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/ftdi_sio/unbind ; echo -n "1-4:1.0" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/ftdi_sio/bind`